# Can't connect two vertices with an edge

Tags: vertices, edges

I'm pretty new to Blender, and what didn't seem to be a challenge to anyone gives me bad trouble. I'm trying to connect two vertices with an edge, they are highlighted in the first picture. However, when I press F with those selected, the edges appear between them and the opposite end of their stroke, as seen in the second picture. What can I do to connect them? Thanks in advance!

[image: The vertices selected]

[image: After pressing F]

Comment: The "F" key closes the **Stroke**, since you have more then one Stroke you want to *join*, did you try pressing the "Ctrl+J" key-combination?

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[Xylvier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/84116/xylvier) pointed out in the comments, I should have done <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join the strokes.